# Proper nesting of Clojure Specs?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I think I may have a problem with the correct order of nesting Specs within a function - specifically `s/with-gen` and `s/or`...

I have this function and Spec:

```
(defn set-gift-pair-in-gift-history [g-hist g-year g-pair]
  (if (nil? g-hist)
    [{:giver :none, :givee :none}]
    (assoc g-hist g-year g-pair)))
(s/fdef set-gift-pair-in-gift-history
        :args (s/with-gen
                (s/or :input-hist (s/and
                                    (s/cat :g-hist :unq/gift-history
                                           :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                                           :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
                                    #(<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %))))
                      :input-nil (s/and
                                   (s/cat :g-hist nil?
                                          :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                                          :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
                                   #(<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %)))))
                #(gen/let [hist (s/gen :unq/gift-history)
                           year (gen/large-integer* {:min 0 :max (max 0 (dec (count hist)))})
                           pair (s/gen :unq/gift-pair)]
                   [hist year pair]))
        :ret :unq/gift-history)
```

Which tests correctly:

```
(stest/check `set-gift-pair-in-gift-history)
=>
({:spec #object[clojure.spec.alpha$fspec_impl$reify__2451
                0x729d93b6
                "clojure.spec.alpha$fspec_impl$reify__2451@729d93b6"],
  :clojure.spec.test.check/ret {:result true,
                                :num-tests 1000,
                                :seed 1531413555637},
  :sym clojure-redpoint.roster/set-gift-pair-in-gift-history})
```

And its parameters conform correctly:

```
(s/conform (s/or :input-hist (s/and
                               (s/cat :g-hist :unq/gift-history
                                      :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                                      :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
                               #(<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %))))
                 :input-nil (s/and
                              (s/cat :g-hist nil?
                                     :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                                     :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
                              #(<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %)))))
           [[{:giver :GeoHar, :givee :JohLen}] 0 {:giver :RinStaXX, :givee :PauMccXX}])
=>
[:input-hist
 {:g-hist [{:giver :GeoHar, :givee :JohLen}],
  :g-year 0,
  :g-pair {:giver :RinStaXX, :givee :PauMccXX}}]

(s/conform (s/or :input-hist (s/and
                               (s/cat :g-hist :unq/gift-history
                                      :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                                      :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
                               #(<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %))))
                 :input-nil (s/and
                              (s/cat :g-hist nil?
                                     :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                                     :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
                              #(<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %)))))
           [nil 0 {:giver :RinStaXX, :givee :PauMccXX}])
=>
[:input-nil
 {:g-hist nil, :g-year 0, :g-pair {:giver :RinStaXX, :givee :PauMccXX}}]
```

But when this "correct" function is consumed by a second function:

```
(defn set-gift-pair-in-roster [plrs-map plr-sym g-year g-pair]
  (let [plr (get-player-in-roster plrs-map plr-sym)
        gh (get-gift-history-in-player plr)
        ngh (set-gift-pair-in-gift-history gh g-year g-pair)
        nplr (set-gift-history-in-player ngh plr)]
    (assoc plrs-map plr-sym nplr)))
(s/fdef set-gift-pair-in-roster
        :args (s/cat :plrs-map ::plr-map
                     :plr-sym keyword?
                     :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                     :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
        :ret ::plr-map)
```

The consumed function becomes a source of error for the consuming function (the `nil` case - which I thought was handled):

```
(stest/check `set-gift-pair-in-roster)
=>
({:spec #object[clojure.spec.alpha$fspec_impl$reify__2451
                0x3bbc704a
                "clojure.spec.alpha$fspec_impl$reify__2451@3bbc704a"],
  :clojure.spec.test.check/ret {:result #error{:cause "Call to #'clojure-redpoint.roster/set-gift-pair-in-gift-history did not conform to spec:
                                                       In: [0] val: nil fails spec: :unq/gift-history at: [:args :input-hist :g-hist] predicate: vector?
                                                       val: {:g-hist nil, :g-year 1, :g-pair {:givee :_+, :giver :RJK/Y24}} fails at: [:args :input-nil] predicate: (<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %)))
```

I have tried changing the order and grouping (nesting) of the specs in the consumed function - but then it fails the tests that it used to pass, before even getting to testing the consuming function.

Any thoughts on what is going wrong here?

Thank you!

EDIT:

As suggested, here is the full code for a better understanding:

```
;Here is an example of The Beatles keeping track of the Xmas gifts
;they give to each other (:giver and :givee) each year over time:

(ns clojure-redpoint.roster2
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
            [orchestra.spec.test :as st]
            [clojure.test.check.generators :as gen]
            [clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest]))

(s/def ::givee keyword?)
(s/def ::giver keyword?)
(s/def :unq/gift-pair (s/keys :req-un [::givee ::giver]))
(s/def ::name string?)
(s/def :unq/gift-history (s/coll-of :unq/gift-pair :kind vector?))
(s/def :unq/player (s/keys :req-un [::name :unq/gift-history]))
(s/def ::plr-map (s/map-of keyword? :unq/player))


(defn- get-player-in-roster [plrs-map plr-sym]
  (get plrs-map plr-sym))
(s/fdef get-player-in-roster
        :args (s/cat :plrs-map ::plr-map :plr-sym keyword?)
        :ret (s/or :found :unq/player
                   :not-found nil?))

(defn- get-gift-history-in-player [plr]
  (get plr :gift-history))
(s/fdef get-gift-history-in-player
        :args (s/or :input-plr (s/cat :plr :unq/player)
                    :input-nil (s/cat :plr nil?))
        :ret (s/or :found :unq/gift-history
                   :not-found nil?))

(defn set-gift-pair-in-gift-history [g-hist g-year g-pair]
  (if (nil? g-hist)
    [{:giver :none, :givee :none}]
    (assoc g-hist g-year g-pair)))
(s/fdef set-gift-pair-in-gift-history
        :args (s/with-gen
                (s/or :input-hist (s/and
                                    (s/cat :g-hist :unq/gift-history
                                           :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                                           :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
                                    #(<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %))))
                      :input-nil (s/and
                                   (s/cat :g-hist nil?
                                          :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                                          :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
                                   #(<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %)))))
                #(gen/let [hist (s/gen :unq/gift-history)
                           year (gen/large-integer* {:min 0 :max (max 0 (dec (count hist)))})
                           pair (s/gen :unq/gift-pair)]
                   [hist year pair]))
        :ret :unq/gift-history)

(defn set-gift-history-in-player [g-hist plr]
  (if (or (nil? g-hist) (nil? plr))
    {:name "none", :gift-history [{:giver :none, :givee :none}]}
    (assoc plr :gift-history g-hist)))
(s/fdef set-gift-history-in-player
        :args (s/or :input-good (s/cat :g-hist :unq/gift-history
                                       :plr :unq/player)
                    :input-hist-nil (s/cat :g-hist nil?
                                           :plr :unq/player)
                    :input-plr-nil (s/cat :g-hist :unq/gift-history
                                          :plr nil?)
                    :input-both-nil (s/cat :g-hist nil?
                                           :plr nil?))
        :ret :unq/player)

(defn set-gift-pair-in-roster [plrs-map plr-sym g-year g-pair]
  (let [plr (get-player-in-roster plrs-map plr-sym)
        gh (get-gift-history-in-player plr)
        ngh (set-gift-pair-in-gift-history gh g-year g-pair)
        nplr (set-gift-history-in-player ngh plr)]
    (assoc plrs-map plr-sym nplr)))
(s/fdef set-gift-pair-in-roster
        :args (s/cat :plrs-map ::plr-map
                     :plr-sym keyword?
                     :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                     :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
        :ret ::plr-map)

(st/instrument)

(def roster-map
  {:RinSta {:name "Ringo Starr", :gift-history [{:giver :RinSta, :givee :PauMcc}]},
   :JohLen {:name "John Lennon", :gift-history [{:giver :JohLen, :givee :GeoHar}]},
   :GeoHar {:name "George Harrison", :gift-history [{:giver :GeoHar, :givee :JohLen}]},
   :PauMcc {:name "Paul McCartney", :gift-history [{:giver :PauMcc, :givee :RinSta}]}})

(s/conform ::plr-map
           (set-gift-pair-in-roster roster-map :PauMcc 0 {:giver :JohLenXXX, :givee :GeoHarXXX}))
;=>
;{:RinSta {:name "Ringo Starr", :gift-history [{:giver :GeoHar, :givee :JohLen}]},
; :JohLen {:name "John Lennon", :gift-history [{:giver :RinSta, :givee :PauMcc}]},
; :GeoHar {:name "George Harrison",
;          :gift-history [{:giver :PauMcc, :givee :RinSta}]},
; :PauMcc {:name "Paul McCartney",
;          :gift-history [{:giver :JohLenXXX, :givee :GeoHarXXX}]}}

;(stest/check `set-gift-pair-in-roster)
```

Unfortunately, it did not help me find my error...

Comment: `:unq/gift-history` is the spec that fails and you're not showing that spec. Try creating a complete, minimal repro (and perhaps you'll discover the answer when you do that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that one of your instrumented functions `set-gift-pair-in-gift-history` is being called with invalid arguments when you `` (stest/check `set-gift-pair-in-roster) ``:

```
CompilerException clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Call to #'playground.so/set-gift-pair-in-gift-history did not conform to spec:
In: [0] val: nil fails spec: :unq/gift-history at: [:args :input-hist :g-hist] predicate: vector?
val: {:g-hist nil, :g-year 1, :g-pair {:givee :A, :giver :A}} fails at: [:args :input-nil] predicate: (<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %)))
```

The `check` output gives us a minimal input to reproduce the error:

```
(set-gift-pair-in-roster {} :A 1 {:givee :A, :giver :A})
```

We can see the first argument to the failing function is nil. Looking at `set-gift-pair-in-gift-history`'s function spec, there's a suspect spec that covers that case:

```
            :input-nil (s/and
                         (s/cat :g-hist nil?
                                :g-year (s/and int? #(> % -1))
                                :g-pair :unq/gift-pair)
                         #(<= (:g-year %) (count (:g-hist %)))))
```

This will only conform when `g-hist` is nil and `g-year` is `0`, but the generator for `:g-year` is going to generate many numbers besides `0`. That's why the calls to it fail when it's `instrument`ed.

`instrument` and `check` have shown a discrepancy between how the program is *specified* to behave and how it actually behaves. I'd start by thinking about how `set-gift-pair-in-gift-history` should be spec'd when its first argument is nil. The implementation doesn't care about the other arguments when the first arg is nil, so you could adjust the function spec to reflect that:

```
:input-nil (s/cat :g-hist nil? :g-year any? :g-pair any?)
```

With that change, your top-level function should `check` successfully.

Comment: Thank you Taylor! I see the logic clash between a nil `g-hist` and a non-zero `g-year` and how your suggestion covers the nil case better. But I don't understand why ``(stest/check `set-gift-pair-in-gift-history)`` didn't catch that on its own? Surely one of those generated test cases would have been nil + non-zero. Do you know why the error is caught as part of ``(stest/check `set-gift-pair-in-roster)`` but not ``(stest/check `set-gift-pair-in-gift-history)``? Thanks again, Eric

Comment: Wait! I think I see it! The reason the 1st spec `check`s correctly on its own is because it uses a custom generator (that you wrote) which never produces a nil + non-zero test case. Its only the 2nd spec which can produce that test case and send it to the 1st function - where it fails. Do I have that right?